# Best technology/database to generate reports on Excel and improve performance?

Tags: sql-server, excel, database, ms-access

Im currently doing a basic report of quantity of products sold and other information on Excel. The problem is that the database (Barcode, Store, Quantity), is a huge database that is currently stored on Excel (around 600.000 rows of information), which makes it really slow to manipulate.

With this data, i compare things like sells this year vs last year and etc. I want to know whats the best technology I can use to store this data in another place and maybe link it to Excel to just read and generate the report.

I've currently studying MS Access, but I've heard that is very limited, so maybe there is better options.

I appreciate every suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Access, just use [Power Pivot for Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-pivot-overview-and-learning-f9001958-7901-4caa-ad80-028a6d2432ed).  Instead of storing the data on a worksheet Power Pivot loads the data into a highly-compressed columnar in-memory store.

This is the same analysis engine used in SQL Server Analysis Services and Power BI.  It will provide fast access over many millions of rows.